# What is plus1filll?

Tags: beamer, spacing

In the beamer manual on pg 64 they introduce the following suggestion on how to insert a horizontal navigation bar

```
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\textwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}
```

They introduce a variable, `plus1filll`, but I can't find information on where this comes from anywhere. I'd like to know: Is it a built-in LaTeX command or introduced by beamer? What does it do?

Comment: That's TeX skip with a glue.